# Retrieve all distinct values in one column that satisfies combination of condition in other column (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a table like so:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
+        x        +        y        +
+-----------------+-----------------+
+        a        +        1        +
+        a        +        2        +
+        b        +        1        +
+        b        +        3        +
+        c        +        1        +
+        c        +        2        +
+        c        +        3        +
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Say I want to find all the distinct rows in x that contain a desired combination of values in y **per group**.

Say the condition is to find all groups where `y = [1,2]`. This would yield `a` and `c`.

Note that the solution needs to scale to any number of combinations in y, for instance `y = [1,2,3]` which would yield `c`.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using, SQL servery?  MySql?

Comment: @EoinS PostgreSQL, but it'd be nice with as general solution to the problem as possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I approach this using `group by` and `having`.  If you want 1 and 2 and anything else:

```
select x
from t
where y in (1, 2)
group by x
having count(distinct y) = 2;
```

The `distinct` would be unnecessary if you knew that x/y pairs were unique.

If you wanted only `1`, because that is an exact match:

```
select x
from t
group by x
having sum(case when y = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when y = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when y not in (1, 2) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using having count(*) = number of element in array

```
 select x from (
 select distinct x, y 
 from my_table where y in (1,2) ) t 
 group by x 
 having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: @salient can you have duplicate values ie (a,1) and (a,1)?  If not this will work.

Comment: @EoinS — yes there can be instances of that.

Answer (score 1):

This solution builds off of the other answers but you can just simply add your list once as mentioned.

You do not have to go and change the list value in your `where` condition and the length of your list in the `count()` function.

```
declare @list varchar(10)
set @list = '1,2,3' --you add this list only

declare @listOfIDs varchar(10);
SET @listOfIDs = concat(',',@list,',');

select x
from p
where charindex(',' + CAST(p.y as nvarchar(20)) + ',', @listOfIDs) >0
group by x
having count(distinct y) = len(@list)-len(replace(@list,',',''))+1;
```

You can play with the different lists [here](http://rextester.com/PRXFB96940)

It should work for `1,305,2` etc

Comment: Very interesting solution. Do you have any idea of how one could also combine this with a solution to find all the unique **occuring** combinations in y? I.e. 1; 2; 3; [1,2]; [1,3]; [2,3]; [1,2,3]?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query.

```
SELECT X
FROM #T
WHERE Y IN (1,2)
GROUP BY X
HAVING COUNT(Y)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Y) FROM #T WHERE Y IN (1,2))
```

You can pass the y column values in a variable using the dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(50)='1,2'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)=
    'SELECT X
    FROM #T
    WHERE Y IN ('+@input+')
    GROUP BY X
    HAVING COUNT(Y)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Y) FROM #T WHERE Y IN ('+@input+'))'
EXEC (@sql)
```

**Sample output**

[image]